# Adding the R-squared for a linear regression plot (ggplot2)?

Tags: r

I've been trying different suggestions such as the `ggmisc` package, but nothing seems to work in my favor.

I'm using the `iris` dataframe and just trying to plot random variables:

```
modellm <- lm(`Sepal.Length` ~ `Sepal.Width` + `Petal.Length` + `Petal.Width`, data = iris)

model <- coef(Modellm)["(Intercept)"] + 
  coef(Modellm)["Sepal.Width"] * iris$`Sepal.Width` + 
  coef(Modellm)["Petal.Length"] * iris$`Petal.Length` + 
  coef(Modellm)["Petal.Width"] * iris$`Petal.Width` + 
  residuals(Modellm)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(`Sepal.Length`, model))+ 
  geom_point(size=2, alpha=0.2)+
  geom_smooth(method='lm')
```

How is it possible for me to get the R-squared value plotted in the ggplot?

Comment: What do you mean by "R-squared value plotted"?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display the r squared value just add this to the end of your plot:

```
 + annotate("text", x = 1, y = 1, label = paste0("R Squared = ", summary(modellm)$r.squared))
```

adjust the placement with the x and y coordinates

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to ***plot*** the R^2, you could do something like this.

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(`Sepal.Length`, model))+ 
  geom_point(size=2, alpha=0.2)+
  geom_smooth(method='lm')

r2 <- summary(Modellm)$r.squared

p + scale_y_continuous(
  sec.axis=sec_axis(~ . * 4 / 30 , name = expression(paste(R^{2})))) +
  geom_rect(xmin=7.9, xmax=8, ymin=0, ymax=1*30/4, 
            fill="white", color="#78B17E") +
  geom_rect(xmin=7.9, xmax=8, ymin=0, ymax=r2*30/4, fill="#78B17E") + 
  annotate("text", x = 7.95, y = 7.62, size=3, color="#78B17E",
           label = paste0(round(r2, 2)))
```

***Yields***

[image]